# Lock the recipient name in Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I have to lock the full name of signer when he or she will sign how to lock the full name of textbox in docusign[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login to DocuSign web app/admin -> Preferences -> Features -> Signature Adoption Configuration -> Check "Lock the recipient name"